# How to use lodash to map an element of a collection and find first that matches criteria?

Tags: lodash

I frequently find myself writing code like this:

```
_.chain([1,2,3]).map(i=>"*"+i+"*").find(i=>i === "*2*").value()
```

or

```
_.chain([1,2,3]).map(i=> i === 2 ? "*"+i+"*" : undefined).find(i=>i !== undefined).value()
```

to transform each element of the collection and get the first element that matches given criteria.

Is there a shorter way to write this in lodash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use _.transform. The code below will get the first element you want, transform the data for you and stop the loop at first match.

```
_.chain(_.range(1,4))
  .transform( (r,v) => !(v === 2 && r.push( `*${v}*`)))
  .head().value()
```

Comment: I don't think this does what I need it to:
1. Does transform function have a return? I don't think it does.
2. This expression will go over each element, I want to stop on the first match.

Comment: the answer for both of your questions: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#transform.